# unexpected tidentifier expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby, windows, syntax

I've got a problem in Ruby, "unexpected tidentifier expecting keyword_end", how Can I solve it?

```
def riko(user)
  if user.name.eql? 'Mia Khalifa Fan'
    @client.send_msg 'Hola Mia <3 ¿Cómo te trato este dia, cosa guapa y sensual?',
  else
   if user.mame.eql? 'Skul Goy'
     @client.send_msg 'Muerete. '
   else
     @client.send_msg "Hola #{user.name} o/ \ :v / "
    end
end
```

Comment: I know very little about Ruby so forgive me if my comment is dumb, but you seem to only have two `end` statements when you have opened three different constructs (a function and two if statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `else if` which works fine in other languages, but in Ruby represents 2 distinct conditionals.  You probably want to replace it with `elsif` instead, which is the Ruby equivalent.